# Explicitly define how LUTs and slices are used in Xilinx XST tool?

Tags: vhdl, fpga, xilinx

I'm trying to implement some very specific behavior of LUTs and slices, written in VHDL for Xilinx Virtex 5 FPGA synthesized using XST tool(s).  I don't know if I can achieve my behavior by having the tools **infer** what I mean, so how do I explicitly direct this to happen?

I'm talking about use of the 6-input LUTs on Virtex5, of which there are 4 of them in a CLB.

I want to explicitly state:
 - Inputs to each of the 4 LUTs within ONE CLB slice
 - Route the 'S' outputs from the 4 XORCYs
 - Specify INPUT of the 'first' MUXCY (C0)
 - Route OUTPUT of the '4th' MUXCY (Cn)
 - Be able to specify the inputs of each LUT of the CLB in a specific order, since they obviously cascade..

Ideally I'd love to just instantiate a 'CLB' in VHDL with all inputs and outputs, and be able to map these..

I researched the documentation pretty heavily and haven't found anything really

Comment: Not a complete answer, just a hint: Yes, I think it's possible and I think it's called "macros". They're described somewhere in the Xilinx doc (I know, it's huge and not so clearly arranged). There's a section that describes all RTL components and the different methods to infer them. Using the Xilinx libraries and those macros, you should be able to do it.

Comment: http://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/sw_manuals/xilinx12_2/virtex5_hdl.pdf Look for LUT5/6. LUT6 description and instantiation module (Verilog/VHDL) is on page 158.

Comment: I went with this and got around to synthesizing tonight, and it works great.  And using LUT6_L and _D and _2 instantiations I think it's possible to be entirely sure you'll get the results you want within a CLB.  I just used LUT6_2 and MUXCY and am getting exactly what I desired.

Answer (score 6):

Saar suggests you use LUT6 to explicitly instantiate a LUT.  I prefer to control technology mapping with a LUT_MAP constraint.  It requires less maintenance and your HDL code remains device agnostic and simulator friendly.

Here is an example.

```
(* LUT_MAP="yes" *)
module mux4(sel, a, b, c, d, o);
input [1:0] sel;
input       a;
input       b;
input       c;
input       d;
output reg  o;

always @* begin
    case(sel)
    2'b00: o <= a;
    2'b01: o <= b;
    2'b10: o <= c;
    2'b11: o <= d;
    endcase
end
endmodule
```

This lets you write arbitrary combinational logic and tell synthesis (XST) that this (up to 6-input, one output) module must be implemented in a single LUT.  If you combine that with KEEP_HIERARCHY and RLOC constraints you can build up RPMs (relationally placed macros).

```
(* KEEP_HIERARCHY="true" *)
module mux4x4p4(sel, a, b, c, d, o);
input  [1:0] sel;
input  [3:0] a;
input  [3:0] b;
input  [3:0] c;
input  [3:0] d;
output [3:0] o;

(* RLOC="X0Y0" *)
mux4 m0(sel, a[0], b[0], c[0], d[0], o[0]);
(* RLOC="X0Y0" *)
mux4 m1(sel, a[1], b[1], c[1], d[1], o[1]);
(* RLOC="X0Y0" *)
mux4 m2(sel, a[2], b[2], c[2], d[2], o[2]);
(* RLOC="X0Y0" *)
mux4 m3(sel, a[3], b[3], c[3], d[3], o[3]);
endmodule
```

There is more information on RPMs for datapaths on my old web site, www.fpgacpu.org.  For example, The Art of High Performance FPGA Design: http://www.fpgacpu.org/log/aug02.html#art

Happy hacking!

Answer (score 2):

You might be able to achieve the desired behaviour using RLOC and BEL constraints. You can embed the constraints in the VHDL:

```
VHDL Syntax

Declare the VHDL constraint as follows:
attribute bel : string;

Specify the VHDL constraint as follows:
attribute bel of {component_name| label_name}: {component|label} is {F|G|FFA|FFB|FFC|FFD|FFX|FFY|XORF|XORG|A6LUT|B6LUT|C6LUT|D6LUT|A5LUT|B5LUT|C5LUT|D5LUT}";
```

Look in the Xilinx Constraints Guide for more details.

See also this post on comp.arch.fpga for some example VHDL: http://newsgroups.derkeiler.com/Archive/Comp/comp.arch.fpga/2008-05/msg00560.html

Comment: This may have worked but I hesitate to try it.  My reason is that I've tried using attributes before to get DSP resources to be used, and found it very unpredictable.  It will work under some circumstances, but in others it seems to be completely ignored.  My colleagues also ran in to exactly the same issues.  Particularly when a design gets large it seems that many of the attribute settings are unreliable.  Your answer may be correct, but just sharing my experience.  Thank you though